# Perl Rename command to add number sequence to folder & filenames (Linux)

Tags: perl, rename

I was wondering if someone would be able to help me create commands that would allow me to add three different types of sequenced numbering to folder & filenames.
I am looking for these commands to be created using the Perl Rename command in Linux for Debian based systems.
Would like them to be for any file type extension so I will use “.ext” as a placeholder in my examples below.

1.) The first one would be a prefix number sequence pattern with two digits.  1-9 get a single “0” padding in front.
"## - filename.ext"

```
01 – Apple.ext
02 – Orange.ext
03 – Banana.ext
10 – Grape.ext
11 – Watermelon.ext
```

2.) The second pattern is a suffix number sequence pattern similar to above.
"filename - ##.ext"

```
Apple - 01.ext
Apple - 02.ext
Apple - 10.ext
```

3.) The third pattern is a suffix number sequence pattern. 1-9 are only one digit, no “0” padding desired.
"filename (#).ext"

```
Apple (1).ext
Apple (2).ext
Apple (3).ext
Apple (10).ext
Apple (11).ext
```

Thank You for any help provided

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Sorry, but this site is not a discussion forum, programming tutorial site or "write my code for me" site.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. 
Also read 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Answer (score 2):

Perl rename is quite strict about variable declarations, so saving state between each filename is not completely trivial.

The expression passed into `rename` is wrapped into a Perl subroutine using an `eval`, and the subroutine is invoked on every filename. So using `my $var` would result in a variable that is reset on each call.

Using pre-existing global variables like `$a` or `$b` are good for "one-liners" but if extra persistent variables are needed, or more complex initialisation, it turns out that simply declaring in a `BEGIN` or using `our` is also possible.

With that, here are some ideas:

```
rename 'BEGIN{$a="01"} s/^/$a - /; $a++' *
```

```
rename 'our $i||="00"; $i++; s/\.ext$/ - $i$&/' *
```

```
rename '++$a; s/\.ext$/ ($a)$&/' *
```

The first two use Perl's magic `++` on a string.
An alternative would be to call `sprintf`. For example:

```
rename '$b = sprintf "%02d", ++$a; s/^/$b - /' *
```

---

Replace `\.ext$` with suitable regex to match your definition of "extension".

Comment: Hey thank you so much for making a post to actually help me.  The first one worked perfectly, 2.) & 3.) worked but not in the way I was looking for which is my fault, the examples I gave were good but not the descriptions themselves, for 2.) & 3.) I was hoping to be able to replace the entire filenames with a specific filename, "Apple" in the examples and then the numbering sequence after.

Comment: Ran out of characters, again thank you so much for your help, I am really new to the Perl Rename command but wow you showed a couple items I have never seen before, never seen anyone use "BEGIN" except in actual Perl scripts and never heard of "sprintf" either.  I had done quite a bit of research for sequential numbering in rename command but couldn't really find anything like the ones I was looking for to even provide a starting point.  I think these can really help others in the future if they look up how achieve something like this.  Other examples I have seen were too specific.

Comment: I have seen many rename commands, but even the %$ENV $a/$b and the Perls magic ++ you mentioned are things I have never seen before.

Comment: Read up on how Perl search and replace works (`perldoc -f s` ; `perldoc perlre`). Your changed spec requires only small tweaks to my examples.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you again for your response, I am unfamiliar with some of the coding choices so I took what little I do know and combined it with some of the items from your code and was able to generate working commands for both 2.) & 3.).  Anyone viewing this in the future just keep in mind that they seem to work but may cause unknown issues.
Figured I would share because as mentioned I feel these could really be helpful to others as well.

I am using "Apple" as the example for filenames and ".ext" as example for file extension.

2.) Produces  “Apple - ##.ext”

```
'our $i||="00"; $i++; s/(.*)(\.[^.]+$)/Apple - $i$2/' *
```

3.) Produces  “Apple (#).ext”

```
'++$a; s/(.*)(\.[^.]+$)/Apple ($a)$2/' *
```

If anyone has any advice to improve these, I am open to hearing them, but for now this is the best I can do, hopefully others will find this helpful in the future.
Thanks again for your help to get me there.